# Simultaneous analytic continuation of $n$ real analytic functions that map the real line to bounded subsets of the positive real halfline

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question: Let $\epsilon>0$. For a number of $n$ entire functions $f_1$,...,$f_n$ that all map the real line to bounded subsets of the positive real half-line, is it possible to find an analytic continuation from the real line to a set $D_\epsilon\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that the sets $\{f_{j}(z)|z\in D_{\epsilon}\}$, $j\in\{1,...,n\}$, all lie in the half-plane $\{w\in\mathbb{C}|\textrm{Re }w>\epsilon\}$ and there are $z_{\epsilon}\in D_\epsilon$ such that $f_{k}(z_{\epsilon})\in(\epsilon,2\epsilon)$ for at least one $k\in\{1,...,n\}$?

Thanks in advance for any pointers towards an answer!

Comment: what is the context of this question?

Comment: It's a problem I ran into. I essentially want to let that se $D_{\epsilon}$ grow in such a way that the boundaries of the sets $\{f_{j}(z)|z\in D_{\epsilon}\}$ get closer and closer to the origin, but do not pass the imaginary axis. So the $f_{k}(z_{\epsilon})$ need only to be close to the origin and have positive real parts. I just thought the shorter statement that the $f_{k}(z_{\epsilon})$ should be in the described interval made understanding the problem easier.